# Java Error illegal start of expression

Tags: java, illegalstateexception

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public static void main (String args[]){
        Time time1 = new Time();
        Time time2 = new Time();

        time2.setTime(555550000L);

        System.out.println("First Time: "+time1.hour+":"+time1.minute+":"+time1.second+);
        System.out.println("Second Time: "+time2.hour+":"+time2.minute+":"+time2.second+);
    }

    public Time() {
        Calendar calen= Calendar.getInstance();
        hour=calen.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute=calen.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        second=calen.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }

    public void setTime(long elapseTime){
        Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(elapseTime);
        hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        second=c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }
}
```

---

I keep getting the following errors and I don't know how to fix them. Help?

- Time.java:14: illegal start of expression
  System.out.println("First Time: "+time1.hour+":"+time1.minute+":"+time1.second+);
- Time.java:15: illegal start of expression
  System.out.println("Second Time: "+time2.hour+":"+time2.minute+":"+time2.second+);
                                                                              ^

Comment: "+time1.second+);  remove the last +'s in your print statements

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `+` at the end.

```
System.out.println("First Time: "+time1.hour+":"+time1.minute+":"+time1.second);
System.out.println("Second Time: "+time2.hour+":"+time2.minute+":"+time2.second);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the trailing `+` at the end of System.out.println lines.
You have to remove it and everything will be fine.

Comment: You mean the trailing + ?